# No muestra los datos con el plugin DataTable

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, adminlte

No muestra los datos con el plugin sino normal ayuda porfa

**Este es el css**

```
<link href="vistas/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
```

**Estos son los javascript**

```
<script src="vistas/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="vistas/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script src="vistas/js/plantilla.js"></script>
```

**Esta es la Tabla**

```
<table class="table table-bordered mt-2 text-center tablas">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Codigo del Área</th>
                            <th>Nombre del Área</th>
                            <th>Acciones</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle">001</td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle">Personal</td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**Este es el Javascript**

```
console.log($(".tablas").DataTable());
```

**Aclaro que en la consola no me sale ningun error del mal direccionamiento de los archivos por lo que he recurrido a su ayuda y muchas gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la sección de javascript veo que te falta agregar la librería de Jquery
y en la sección de CSS la librería del bootstrap

Replique tu código en este link [Datatables](https://codepen.io/juanmhs/pen/xxGxzVL)

Te dejo un enlace a la documentación de datatables con el estilo de [bootstrap](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias crack si funciono